# check for cast conversion (as dynamic_cast) of a Template class that can be non polymorphic type

Tags: casting, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I have a template member in my class and I'd like to know if the class of this member inherits from a specific class.

```
class BaseClass;  
template <typename T>  
class MyClass  
{  
    T* my_member;  
public:  
    void function()  
    {  
        BaseClass * base = dynamic_cast<BaseClass*>(my_member)  
        if(base != 0)
        {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
        else
        {
            // DO SOMETHING ELSE
        }
    }  
};
```

I know that dynamic_cast doesn't compile if the class of `my_member`isn't polymorphic but I have no control on the Template Class it can be of polymorphic type or not (I am writing a library and my users can use any class they'd like).
Doesn't any one have an idea to implement this in a way that it compiles whether T is polymorphic or not? 
Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [is_polymorphic Boost type trait](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_polymorphic.html) is the one you are looking for. You might want to take a look at [the other type traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) as well if there is one better suited for the task. Beware though, a lot of them are unimplemented, always check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I have been running into the same issue where I have a generic class whose type T is not known (library use) and as a result T may or may not be polymorphic yet I need to use `dynamic_cast` to implement some behavior.

I am not sure this is the best solution, but I was able to write a "generic" dynamic cast which compiles differently based on T using SFINAE (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

```
template<typename U>
class Cast
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  static inline U dynamic(T *iPtr, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_polymorphic<T>::value>::type * = nullptr)
  {
    return nullptr;
  }

  template<typename T>
  static inline U dynamic(T *iPtr, typename std::enable_if<std::is_polymorphic<T>::value>::type * = nullptr)
  {
    return dynamic_cast<U>(iPtr);
  }
};
```

So for your specific example it becomes

```
void function()  
{  
    BaseClass * base = Cast<BaseClass *>::dynamic(my_member);  
    if(base != 0)
    {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
    else
    {
        // DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
}
```